# How to "print" in pyqt5 while inside a function?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm creating a program (for web scraping) and I would like to create a place that shows what the script is doing (as it is already possible through print's on the console) but in the PyQt5 textEdit. (the script is inside of a function on python file)

**However while the function/script is running the GUI crashes and does not show anything until the end of the function/script.**

I made a simplified version to help understand the problem and make it easier to solve. If it works on this one it will probably work on the other.

### Python File

```py
print('iniciando programa...')
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import time

def F_exemplof(): #function thats print index in 2 seconds
    for a in range(20):
        print('Print index: ' + str(a))
        W_exemplogui.textEdit.append('Print index: ' + str(a))
        time.sleep(2)


# Importing the GUI
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
W_exemplogui = uic.loadUi('testegui.ui')

# Buttons
W_exemplogui.pushButton.clicked.connect(F_exemplof)
#W_exemplogui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect()


# Show window
W_exemplogui.show()
app.exec()
```

### testegui.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>383</width>
    <height>304</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" rowstretch="0">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Iniciar</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Cancelar</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
        <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time-consuming tasks must be executed in a secondary thread to avoid blocking the GUI, and signals must be used to send information to the main thread.

```
import threading
import time

from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Task(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        for a in range(20):
            print("Print index: " + str(a))
            self.messageChanged.emit("Print index: " + str(a))
            time.sleep(2)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    W_exemplogui = uic.loadUi("testegui.ui")
    task = Task()
    W_exemplogui.pushButton.clicked.connect(task.start)
    task.messageChanged.connect(W_exemplogui.textEdit.append)
    W_exemplogui.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```